# SQL Sever 2008 / Office 2007 Full text index issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, ifilter

Server is running 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit and SQL Server 2008 R2 Workgroup Edition (64-bit)

We store documents in a varbinay(max) and the full text indexes work perfectly for all document types including PDF’s but do not work for Office 2007 documents.

We have installed the Office 2007 iFilter and done each step  but still do not get any hits.  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;945934

Anyone successfully indexing Office 2007 Docs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a TYPE COLUMN to your table to hold the file extension and specify that TYPE COLUMN when you [created the fulltext index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)?

For example:

```
create table Example (
    MyDocument varbinary(max),
    FileExtension char(5) /* '.doc', '.xls', etc. */
)

create fulltext index on Example
    (MyDocument TYPE COLUMN FileExtension)
```

Comment: Yes, this index has been in place and worked very well until we started putting office 2007 docs in.